# Do you mind + gerund OR if

Tags: grammar

Which sentence grammatically sounds more correct:

> - Do you mind if you wait here a few minutes?
> - Do you mind waiting here a few minutes?

For me both sound absolutely idiomatic and natural.

Added: I have read the similar thread, but unfortunately it didn't help about this specific sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mind waiting here....sounds very normal.  There is something logically inconsistent about the other sentence with the if-clause. You can logically say, 'Do you mind if I wait here?' However to ask, "If you wait here, do you mind?" to me is logically screwy, since if they minded they wouldn't wait there in the first place.

Comment: I mostly agree; however, there are situations where it might make sense. Suppose you came to see me, but there were no free chairs outside my office. In that situation, my receptionist might say, "Do you mind if you wait here a few minutes? Or would you rather go back into the lobby where you can sit down?"

Comment: @J.R. Even in your example, "Do you mind if you wait here..." sounds odd. If I was waiting, I wouldn't mind. If I minded, I wouldn't be waiting.  I probably would get so caught on the first sentence I wouldn't even hear the second bit about sitting in the lobby, and would be super confused. It would still be better to ask "Do you mind waiting here a few minutes, or would you..." with the emphasis on 'here'.

Comment: @DC - I think you and I both agree that this is an awkward construct that would be of very limited use in actual conversation.

Answer (score 0):

The verb *mind* has a *verb pattern* of taking *gerund*. That is [verb + -ing](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode30/languagepoint.shtml)

So, in the title 'mind + gerund' looks okay but comparing it ***grammatically*** with 'mind + if' does not happen that way [Yes, it might have been 'mind + gerund' OR 'mind + to' -but that's not the case which is clear from your examples].

And your first sentence uses the *conjunction* 'if' (and ***not*** verb) and thus it has nothing to do with the rule!

> Do you ***mind waiting*** here... - widely accepted
>   Do you ***mind to wait*** here.... - not accepted

And...

> Do you ***mind*** *if*..... [can be anything] -so your first sentence is okay.

So to answer...

There is nothing like **more correct**, both sentences are okay. But to me, the first sentence in that context uses the pronoun redundantly.

Comment: The problem isn't the lack of a gerund. People often say "Do you mind if I [verb phrase]" or "Do you mind if they [verb phrase]". It's the combination of 'mind', 'if', and 'you' in the predicate that causes difficulty.

Comment: Actually, I'm not even sure what you're trying to say here. Are you saying they're both fine? Why are you talking about infinitives ('to')?

Answer (score -3):

What I learned in school was: *Would you mind + gerund* (*verb+ing*), as in:

> *Would you mind waiting here a few minutes?*